# Packets do not cross IP tables Postrouting when originating from an external IP

Tags: iptables, routing

I'm trying to reflect traffic from the internet to an internal device that I only want to have local access. I have a host in my DMZ that I'm trying to DNAT traffic to this internal device, and SNAT so no internet route is needed.

In testing, I am able to DNAT/SNAT from a local computer to this proxy host and access the resources on the internal device. However when accessing the port on my router, I can see the requests arriving at proxy host via tcpdump, and I see them increment the iptables DNAT rule counter, yet no connection is made. Further more local tests increment both the DNAT and SNAT rule counters, but external traffic only increments the DNAT counter.

The proxy host was spun up for only this purpose and has no other services. There is one interface with two IPs .254 and .253, Incoming traffic should come to .254 and be SNAT'd from .253 on its way to the internal device. Kernel IPv4 forwarding is also enabled.

Below is my iptables config:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sun Jun 22 22:49:18 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [32:4832]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [14:1016]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 7
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i admin -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i admin -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i local -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5308 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i admin -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 10050 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.254.254.1/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -mm
 tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jun 22 22:49:18 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sun Jun 22 22:49:18 2014
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [73:6562]
:INPUT ACCEPT [33:4290]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [18:972]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [18:1408]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [27:1624]
-A INPUT -s 173.214.161.60 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x6/0xffffffff
-A FORWARD -s 173.214.161.60 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x5/0xffffffff
-A POSTROUTING -s 173.214.161.60 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4/0xffffffff
-A PREROUTING -s 173.214.161.60 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x3/0xffffffff
-A OUTPUT -s 173.214.161.60 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jun 22 22:49:18 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sun Jun 22 22:49:18 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [31:3139]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [14:1016]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [14:1016]
-A PREROUTING -d 10.254.254.254/32 -i dmz -j DNAT --to-destination 10.254.254.2
-A POSTROUTING -o dmz -j SNAT --to-source 10.254.254.253
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jun 22 22:49:18 2014
```